# Remove a variable of a class from another part of the code

Tags: android, class, kotlin, parameters, global-variables

I have a class that I pass as a parameter to a function.
This class contains various companion objects.

The class:

```
class GeneralConfiguration {

lateinit var planets: MutableMap<String, String>
lateinit var stars: MutableMap<String, String>
lateinit var comets: MutableMap<String, String>

class newConfiguration {

    companion object {

        const val SIZE = "general_size"
        const val TEXTURE = "general_texture"
        const val WEIGHT = "general_weight"
        const val COLOR = "general_color"
        const val GRAVITY = "general_gravity"
    
    }
}
}
```

To do a test, I need to pass that class as a parameter to the function, but having previously eliminated one of the variables, for example: "COLOR"

My intention is to make a test that is missing the variable "COLOR"

This is just an example, something like:

```
GeneralConfiguration.Remove(newConfiguration.COLOR)

myFoo(Param1, Param2, GeneralConfiguration) //Class with the variable already removed
```

Is it possible to remove one of those variables programmatically before passing the class as a parameter?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can not remove the variable programmatically after you declare it.But you can set value "null" to that variable and pass that class instance into method .Then Do null check for variables  before write your test logic.

Comment: @androidLearner His "variable" is a parameter in a map.  He can absolutely remove an element from a map.  It's variable.remove(key).  He'd just have to do that before passing it in

Comment: He is asking about string variable within companion object .@GabeSechan